# How to execute @SpringBootTest from terminal using mvn command?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, testng

I am trying to get the terminal command to execute SpringBootTest. Something similar to **mvn spring-boot:run**. This command triggers SpringBootApplication.

But I want to trigger SpringBootTest from the terminal using maven command with runtime maven arguments. Do any of you guys know any similar command for triggering SpringBootTest?

**My code looks like below:**

```
@SpringBootTest
class SeosSdkAutomationApplicationTests {

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
        System.out.println("Hello!!");
        TestNG tng = new TestNG();
        XmlSuite suite = new XmlSuite();
        suite.setName("Appium Test suite");
        XmlTest test = new XmlTest(suite);
        test.setName("Sample Test");
        List<XmlClass> classes = new ArrayList<>();
        classes.add(new XmlClass("com.org.TestNGClass_sample"));
        test.setXmlClasses(classes);
        List<XmlSuite> suites = new ArrayList<>();
        suites.add(suite);
        tng.setXmlSuites(suites);
        tng.run();

    }
```

I am programmatically triggering testng using spring. I need spring framework for dependency injection in testng test cases. Please help out. I tried all the possibilities

Comment: `mvn test`. Just run the tests as usale. Also why use junit to launch a testng test?! Your setup looks flawed.

Comment: @M.Deinum I tried mvn test earlier itself. Maven test will execute all the test cases in the entire project. But programmatic testng will execute the test cases based on the mvn runtime arguments. So I cannot use mvn test.

Comment: @M.Deinum  I need maven + spring + testng. Maven to execute the suite with runtime parameters, spring for dependency injection and testng for my testcases. So I am using Springboot test to execute my testng test.

Comment: I strongly recommend to go with JUnit JUpiter and remove the dependency to TestNG that will make life easier....or you need to execlude JUnit Jupiter ...

Comment: I don't understand why you use a test method to launch a test suite, and also mark that as a springboottest. This whole setup doesn't make anysense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your suggestions friends. After a lot of trial and error, I got a solution. It's just a workaround. Instead of running the main class as a Springboottest, I triggered it as the Main class with scope as test, from maven command. Please find my code and the solution to trigger the code,

**Main Class to trigger test suite**

```
import java.util.List;

class Sample {

public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello!!");
        TestNG tng = new TestNG();
        XmlSuite suite = new XmlSuite();
        suite.setName("Appium Test suite");
        XmlTest test = new XmlTest(suite);
        test.setName("Sample Test");
        List<XmlClass> classes = new ArrayList<>();
        classes.add(new XmlClass("org.test.TestNGClass_sample"));
        test.setXmlClasses(classes);
        List<XmlSuite> suites = new ArrayList<>();
        suites.add(suite);
        tng.setXmlSuites(suites);
        tng.run();

}
```

**Bean One:**

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class BeanOne {

    public BeanOne createBean(){
        return new BeanOne();
    }

    public void printBeanOne(){
        System.out.println("Bean One");
    }

}
```

**Bean Two**

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class BeanTwo {

    public BeanTwo createBean(){
        return new BeanTwo();
    }

    public void printBeanTwo(){
        System.out.println("Bean Two!!");
    }
}
```

**TestNG Class:**

```
@SpringBootTest
public class TestNGClass_sample extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {

    @Autowired
    public BeanOne beanOne;

    @Autowired
    public BeanTwo beanTwo;

    @Test
    public void test(){
        beanOne.printBeanOne();
        beanTwo.printBeanTwo();
    }

    @Test
    public void test2(){
        System.out.println("Test2");
    }

    @Test
    public void test3(){
        System.out.println("Test3");
    }
}
```

**pom.xml configuration**

```
...
    <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <mainClass>org.test.Sample</mainClass>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
...
```

**Output:**

```
.   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.6.RELEASE)

2020-03-31 22:51:00.391  INFO 24148 --- [ionTests.main()] s.s.a.s.TestNGClass_sample               : Started TestNGClass_sample in 0.653 seconds (JVM running for 3.29)
Bean One
Bean Two!!
Test2
Test3

===============================================
Appium Test suite
Total tests run: 3, Passes: 3, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
```

**Solution to trigger the main class:**

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=“org.test.Sample” -Dexec.classpathScope=test
```

Answer (score 3):

You might want to run

```
mvn -Dtest=SeosSdkAutomationApplicationTests test
```

in the directory that contains your pom.xml file to execute just this one test class.

But as @M.Deinum said, your setup looks flawed, trying to execute a TestNG test inside a Junit test.

Comment: I am sorry, the solution provided did not work. No test cases were run upon executing this command. The reason for using spring to trigger testng is,  I need maven + spring + testng. Maven to execute the suite with runtime parameters, spring for dependency injection and testng for my testcases. So I am using Springboot test to execute my testng test. I have integrated all three. I just need the command to trigger the spring boot test

Comment: Why do you need TestNG in relationship Spring boot ? Spring Boot usually is using JUnit 4 and newer versions are on JUnit Jupiter (aka JUnit 5)? ...

Comment: @khmarbaise,  Testng has more advantages like reporting when you compare it with junit. I need spring for dependency injection. I am creating an appium test automation framework, and spring will help me manage the appiumDriver bean object.

Comment: TestNG comparing with JUnit Jupiter will leave only very few advantages like method dependencies. And yes using spring DI is Ok...but I don't understand the relationship to TestNG...best would be to produce a simple example on GitHub which shows the problem ...is much easier than doing long discussions via q/a ping pong...